# Send Woocommerce Order to email address listed on product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I'm using Woocommerce and the Product Addons plugin to add extra fields to a product. One of those fields is an email address to let people send the confirmation of the order to a DIFFERENT address than the billing address shown on the checkout page. Emails should be sent to both addresses.

Any thoughts on maybe how to modify the functions.php file to do this?

Comment: As you can have many items for an order, this additional email field should not be a product custom field, but an additional checkout field. Think it…

Comment: There may be more than one product in the cart but thr email is being requested for on the product page itself as a "first step". It is assumed that the confirmation of a purchase will always go to the same address, but it could differ from the billing address, which is why it needs to appear on the product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **`woocommerce_email_recipient_{$this->id}`** filter hook, you can use the `$order` argument to get your 2nd email.

But first Lets add globally an email field with the Product Add-ons plugin…

1. The add on field on the product (fill the field and add to cart):

[image]

2. This "Email" field in order-received (Thank you) page, after checkout:

[image]

As you can notice the label of this field is "Email"…

Now if I look in the database in **`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`** for this order I can see for the `meta_key "Email"` the `meta_value "loic@TheAztec.com"` :

[image]

Now I can set the correct `meta_key` in the code below to get my email.

Here is the code that will add this additional email recipient for processing and completed customer order email notifications:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'additional_customer_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // Processing Order
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'additional_customer_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // Completed Order
function additional_customer_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    $additional_recipients = array(); // Initializing…

    // Iterating though each order item
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ){
        // HERE set the the correct meta_key (like 'Email') to get the correct value
        $email = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Email', true );

        // Avoiding duplicates (if many items with many emails)
        // or an existing email in the recipient
        if( ! in_array( $email, $additional_recipients ) && strpos( $recipient, $email ) === false )
            $additional_recipients[] = $email;
    }

    // Convert the array in a coma separated string
    $additional_recipients = implode( ',', $additional_recipients);

    // If an additional recipient exist, we add it
    if( count($additional_recipients) > 0)
        $recipient .= ','.$additional_recipients;

    return $recipient;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try to implement this and will tick correct if it works on my end.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Now just have to make sure this is what the client wants lol :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in your function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'your_email_recipient_filter_function', 10, 2);

function your_email_recipient_filter_function($recipient, $object) {
    $recipient = $recipient . ', me@myemail.com';
    return $recipient;
}
```

and if you want to send email in BCC then please try below code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'mycustom_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);

function mycustom_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
    if ($object == 'customer_completed_order') {
        $headers .= 'BCC: My name <my@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but I can't hard code the email address. It must come from a field that appears on the product's page itself. It also can't come from the checkout page (or billing address). I don't think your solution does that...