# Woocommerce: How to debug problem related to new order email?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I used this solution to send emails to additional recipients with custom fields

[Add recipients from product custom fields to Woocommerce new order email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910924/add-recipients-from-product-custom-fields-to-woocommerce-new-order-email-notific?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

However I do not receive any email. 
I turned on debug, debug log and debug display, but it does not show any error.

I think it could be error in mail service which I use to send order emails (I use Mail.ru SMTP). 
However it works without the code.

The question is how to find the problem?

**UPD**:
I added to  `var_dump($recipient); die;` before `return $recipient;` and received an error in error_log:

```
string(45) "order@domain.name, email@domain.name, email2@domain.name"
```

**UPD2**:
I turned on email log in plugin settings, and received this technical details:

```
Date: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 09:56:35 +0000
To: order@domain.name, email@domain.name, email2@domain.name
From: Hello Hello <hello@domain.name>
Reply-To: A A <customer@domain.name>
Subject: [Domain.name]: New order #1234
Message-ID: <c2654ca64fd38e5061f7357d04b1XXXX@domain.name>
X-Mailer: WPMailSMTP/Mailer/smtp 1.9.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Unfortunately I did not receive any message in any of emails.

**UPD3**:
I installed email-log plugin to monitor email statuses, and it shows error in email which should be sent to order@domain.name, email@domain.name, email2@domain.name

Comment: Instead of putting dislikes, it would be much helpful if you help!

Comment: Have you echo'd or logged the value of `$recipient` to confirm it is populated they way you think it is?

Comment: No, could you please tell how to do it?

Comment: The most direct way would be to add `vardump($recipient); die;` as a new line above your return statement. This will render out the recipient variable with type information then terminate the script.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to log and received an error in error_log (I've updated the post, please see above). As I understand the problem is that I have Array instead of email names.

Comment: It’s `var_dump`, not `vardump`.

Comment: Now it shows all my unique emails which I indicated in each product: string(45) "order@domain.name,email@domain.name,email2@domain.name"

Comment: Have you tried a plugin like [email-log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-log/). This way you can determine whether the mails are sent from wordpress and the problem is therefore elsewhere (email spam filter, etc ..)

Comment: I installed email-log plugin, the log shows error in Sent Status column. However WP SMTP plugin shows that all emails sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to turn off the script and manually added 2 emails in New Order settings in WooCommerce setting page.
As a result, I do not receive any mails when I have more than 1 recipient.

I've written to support-team of biz.mail.ru and they kindly asked me to provide SMTP logs.

**As a result, the script works well and in order to check it you can use code in UPD1.**

I think I should look for ways how to log SMTP and solve this problem with the mail service provider.

In case the problem will be on my side I will update (or ask to update) this question.
Kind regards.