# Replacement recipient from order custom field on WooCommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, email-notifications

I created a new field in the checkout part using the a checkout field plugin. This field allows customer to specify a third email address outside of the billing or shipping address. I want to send the order confirmation only to this address and not to the billing part.

After several searches, I used [Send Woocommerce Order to email address listed on product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065289/send-woocommerce-order-to-email-address-listed-on-product-page/47079780#47079780) answer code, replacing the order item meta key `'email'` by `'billing_email_guest'` like:

```
$email = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'billing_email_guest', true );
```

But it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct way as this is about custom order meta data, but not **order item** meta data.

Try the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_on_hold_order', 'additional_customer_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // On hold Order
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'additional_customer_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // Processing Order
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'additional_customer_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // Completed Order
function additional_customer_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) 
        return $recipient;

    $billing_email_guest = $order->get_meta('billing_email_guest');
    if( ! empty($billing_email_guest) ) {
        return $billing_email_guest;
    }

    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.